# How to disable the past dates on the date picker .Tried all solutions provided on stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have tried `mindate:0` but it is not working for my code.I have tried for the solutions on stack overflow but unable to adapt it to my code.I wish to disable the past dates on the **datepicker**. Kindly help me .This is my code:-

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#departing").datepicker({onSelect: function() {

        var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here is one Example i created for you : http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/3479/ using your previous approach. Does this help? Are you using jQuery UI datepicker? If yes could you specify the version?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.Your code is working in my code also.But just a suggestion.Can i use it with the onselect function  i have used it? If yes,then how.Because without it, this is working.Thanx a tonne.And yes i am using jquery ui date picker

Comment: Of Course you can : http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/3480/

Comment: Thanx a lot sir :) Your help worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may help you. Please try this code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var dateToday = new Date();
        $("#departing").datepicker({
            minDate: dateToday,
            onSelect: function() {
                var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
            }
        });
   });
</script>
```